# How to go to the next line in an assembly file

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm writing in assembly 8086 tasm and I'm trying to move to the next line in the current file via the code:

```
stam db 20 dup(?), 10, 13
...
mov ah,40h
mov bx,[filehandle]
mov cx,22
mov dx,offset stam
int 21h
```

It's just making some spaces.. no new lines.

Comment: Array has 22 bytes, you write 12. Of course the newline isn't written

Comment: You right.. well i changed cx to 22.. but yet it does't work..

Comment: I actually noticed that the 10, 13 in the end of a string doesn't working even in the dosbox.. so what should I put in end of a string in order to go the next line?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I found the problem.. I just change the place of the 10 with the 13.. like stam db 20 dup(?), 13, 10 and it worked. Super annoying :)